# Comparing items of a tuple within a list of tuples

Tags: python, math, lambda, tuples, list-comprehension

I have designed a program to calculate some maximum tuples from a list, however I am stuck at the point where I have to compare the maximum `item[1]` from a tuple and compare it to another tuple `item[1]`.
This is the list of tuples:

```
fff = []
anslist = [(2, [1]), (3, [7]), (4, [2]), (5, [5]), (6, [8]), (7, [16]), (8, [3]), (9, [19]), (10, [6]), (11, [14]), (12, [9]), (13, [9]), (14, [17]), (15, [17]), (16, [4]), (17, [12]), (18, [20]), (19, [20]), (20, [7])]
```

This is the code I have:

```
print(max(anslist, key=lambda x: x[1]))
fff.append(max(anslist, key=lambda x: x[1]))
anslist.remove(max(anslist, key=lambda x: x[1]))
while (max(fff[1], key=lambda x: x[1])) == (max(anslist[1], key=lambda x: x[1])):
     print(max(anslist, key=lambda x: x[1]))
     anslist.remove(max(anslist, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

I expect my program to print (18, [20]) and (19, [20]), and because the list of tuples always changes in response to the users input I needed some kind of loop which needed to go through all tuples until the second item of the tuple is not the largest anymore.

This is the error I get :

```
while (max(fff[1], key=lambda x: x[1])) == (max(anslist[1], key=lambda x: x[1])):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: I have edited your question to be a bit better, but please [edit] it to include how your code attempts fail to solve the problem. Give real output - "not working" is completely unhelpful information.

Comment: A quick tip unrelated to your question: When you find yourself passing an identical `lambda` many times over, assign it to a variable and pass the variable instead. A bonus of this approach is that if you wanted to modify the way the `lambda` worked, you'd only have to change it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your subscript `[1]` which is in the wrong position.

Instead of:

```
while (max(fff[1], key=lambda x: x[1])) == (max(anslist[1], key=lambda x: x[1])):
```

This is what you want:

```
while max(fff, key=lambda x: x[1])[1] == max(anslist, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]:
```

That prints `(19, [20])` as you expect.

(I also removed all unneeded parens from your expression.)

A much more efficient way to do this is to find the max only once and filter the list based on that:

```
max_element = max(x[1] for x in anslist)
max_tuples = [x for x in anslist if x[1] == max_element]
```

Also interesting is sorting anslist to put `(18, [20])` and `(19, [20])` in front, after which you can use a simple `for` loop and break when the second element of the tuple changes.

```
sorted_anslist = sorted(anslist, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked. Im still learning to be more efficient, thanks a lot.